# Math mode character spacing

Tags: math-mode, kerning

I am writing a solution to a geometry exercise. I use $AB$ for the length of the line, or arc, from A to B. This results in a larger than desired spacing between the two characters. I can 'fix' it with $A\!B$ for every line or arc in my solution. (I am using both inline and display math.) Is there a 'nicer' or more global way of achieving this?

Comment: Consider making a `\newcommand`.

Comment: `\mathit{AB} `, probably a good idea to make it a macro

Comment: The result of `$A\!B$` is awfully bad. Can you please show an example of what you're doing? Just for information, the space between letters in `$\mathit{AB}$` is slightly *bigger* than the space in `$AB$` (where the letters are slightly wider, though).

Answer (score 1):

Inside math all letters are treated as individual math variables, so some predefined space will come by default, better to use `\mathit`, where you want to treat as normal text with italic...

PS: Note that it is helpful if you provide a `MWE` of what you tried, then will check the possibility to fix this issue in some other way...(if possible :-) )